# How to use route a controller in and out of namespace in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I'm new to Rails and a bit confused how the namespace works. Basically I have categories and customers controllers.

I want to create an admin namespace (which I don't understand yet) so certain methods to be accessed only through `/admin/products/id, via: 'delete'` (`/admin/...` being the important part) namespace while other methods would be accessed normally like so: `/products, via: 'get'`

If I understood correctly, in order to create a namespace, I need to create a subdirectory and have the controllers within this directory, but I guess in that case it'll no longer be accessible normally?

Is this possible? How?

I've tried (for instance)

```
match '/admin/products',    to: 'admin#index', via: 'get'
```

but it gave me an error saying that a variable (in the template) was not available. However when I tried without the `/admin` it worked fine, which implies that the problem is the namespace situation.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you were having?

Comment: The exact error is: `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass` thats is triggered by the template (a `@user` is passed to the template). The parameters passed are: {"id"=>"customers"} when visiting /admin/customers which tells me that the route is not recognised

Comment: Check this link out. It really helped me understand http://blog.roberteshleman.com/2014/08/14/using-rails-namespaces-for-admin-actions/

Answer (score 3):

If you add the following namespace to your `route.rb`

```
namespace :admin do
  resources : categories
  resources : customers
end
```

You can create the following controllers in `controllers/admin` folder:

```
#base_controller.rb - will work like your application_controller for the namespace
class Admin::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  ...
end

#categories_controller.rb - will work like your categories_controller for the namespace
class Admin::CategoriesController < Admin::BaseController
  ...
end

#customers_controller.rb - will work like your customers_controller for the namespace
class Admin::CustomersController < Admin::BaseController
  ...
end
```

In this way, you can add authentication in the base controller, giving full access for administrators, and remove actions like `delete`, `edit` from your non namespaced part.

I hope it helps...

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The route is not recognised and I got the same error

Answer (score -1):

A `namespace` is the equivalence of a module for your controllers.

Simply, you'll have to do the following:

> - Put your namespaced controllers into a subdirectory of the same name
> - All your routes need to be sent through the namespaced helpers

Here's how to do this:

---

**Namespace**

You'd be in the best position by reading up on [namespacing from the Rails documents](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

If you wanted to make an "admin" namespace, you'd do the following (we use this):

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root "products#index"

   resources :products, only: [:new, :create]
   resources :customers, only: [:new, :create]
end

resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
resources :customers, only: [:index, :show]
```

This will create a number of routes for you; but the namespaced ones will only provide

Here's how to construct your controllers:

```
#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authenticate_user!
end

#app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def index
      @products = Product.all
   end
end
```

This will provide you with an authentication-only area to provide access to the creation of `Product` and `Category` objects.

If you want to route to these controllers, you'll need to use the provided namespaced routes:

```
<%= link_to "New Product", admin_product_path if user_signed_in? %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I copied your code letter by letter, tried with small variations, but always got the same error: A variable that was defined in my controller was not defined (because the method was not being reached) and the params were admin :id => categories which implies that Rails saw the `categories` in  `/admin/categories` as a parameter rather than route. Also, I'm using Rails 4 with Mongoid. Does that make any difference?